# How to fix method in in trait ScopingSetting is deprecated warning in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I am getting a warning in SBT to migrate to newer slash syntax for the below.

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.alvinalexander.testproject.Foo")
```

Error:
build.sbt:18: warning: method in in trait ScopingSetting is deprecated (since 1.5.0): `in` is deprecated; migrate to slash syntax - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#slash
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.alvinalexander.testproject.Foo")

Not sure how to use the slash syntax for the above. I tried the below but didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
(Compile, run) / mainClass := Some("com.alvinalexander.testproject.Foo")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Compile / run / mainClass := Some("com.alvinalexander.testproject.Foo")
```